# SELECT SQL найти строку

Tags: android, java, like, select, sql

Я могу найти нужную мне строку через `like`, однако, мне нужно получить не всю строку (колонку строки), а только часть, где она упоминается. Например, если у нас текст:

> "ХэшКод - это совместно редактируемый форум вопросов и ответов для начинающих и опытных программистов. Присоединяйтесь!"

То по запросу "ответов" я хочу увидеть в ответ:

> "вопросов и ответов для начинающих",

что бы потом пользователю вывести

> "...вопросов и ответов для начинающих...".

База *sqlite*, платформа *Android*

Comment: Вам надо SQL запрос, который бы обрезал и вывел серединку текста или же пост обработку на Java? Если первое, то для какой СУБД?

Comment: Что бы бд сама. Я писал: "База sqlite"

Comment: а вы уже придумали условие по которому вам будет выведено верное кол-во слов с момента совпадения?

Comment: А нет что то есть: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html 
Функция substr

Comment: Не выйдет, sqlite не имеет встроенной функции для получения индекса подстроки.

Comment: Печаль. Как-то не очень всю строку, размером в 100 символов доставать (с учетом, что нужно будет еще пару сотен таких запросов).

Comment: @Anatoliy, а почему вы решили, что это даст хоть какие-то проблемы с производительностью? Или просто решили заняться преждевременной оптимизацией? Скорее всего, эти данные вы будете представлять в UI в списочном виде, где `Cursor` отлично разрулит все проблемы, поскольку он умеет работать через SQLite'овский query frame.